# Not enough privilege to view users in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, windows, server, phpmyadmin, xampp

I can't see users in **phpmyadmin** on windows server 2012. It gives the error:

> Not enough privilege to view users.
>
> Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#213  mysqli_query(): (HY000/1194): Table 'user' is marked as crashed and
>   should be repaired

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

The error, `Not enough privilege to view users` in phpmyadmin can also occur when importing an older MySQL database into a newer MariaDB instance via a SQL dump due to changes in how the users are stored.

**Other symptoms include:**

1. The command `select * FROM mysql.user;` returns the error message:

   ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
2. The command `select * FROM mysql.tables_priv;` returns an empty result set.

**The solution:**

As the database root user, run the following queries:

```
use mysql;

INSERT INTO `tables_priv` (`Host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`, `Grantor`, `Timestamp`, `Table_priv`, `Column_priv`) VALUES ('localhost','mysql','mariadb.sys','global_priv','root@localhost','0000-00-00 00:00:00','Select,Delete','');
```

Then restart the MariaDB server.

**Credit:** IgorG on the Plesk forums. (https://talk.plesk.com/threads/view-mysql-user-references-invalid-table-s-or-column-s-or-function-s-or-definer-invoker-of-view-lack-rights-to-use-them.363334/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to repair your user table. Use a SQL query like 'REPAIR TABLE user' or repair it using phpmyadmin .

Answer (score 0):

Go to xampp\mysql\bin in Command Prompt and Try to execute following command,

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases
(Password prompted - Press enter if blank)
```

Hope it will work for you.
All the best.

http://www.gnhub.com